# Running spock integrations tests in its own folder in maven

Tags: maven, integration-testing, spock

I am trying to only run integration tests in maven with mvn. I have my tests in src/it/java for java integration tests and src/it/groovy for Spock integration tests. When I run mvn failsafe:integration-test, only the java integration tests in src/it/java are run.

This is my pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-integration-test-source</id>
      <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sources>
          <source>src/it/java</source>
          <source>src/it/groovy</source>
        </sources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/it/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <testSources>
      <testSource>
        <directory>src/it/groovy</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*IT.groovy</include>
        </includes>
      </testSource>
    </testSources>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>groovy-compile</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>compileTests</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that your running only failsafe:integration-test.  I am able to run groovy and java tests using the command:

```
mvn verify
```

In the failsafe docs it suggests to use the verify phase here - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html

If mvn verify still doesn't run your groovy tests, check your_project/target/test-classes/path_to_your_test for expected class files and make sure that lines up with  the includes option in the pom.